# Does the order of variables in a Markov Regime Switching model matter?

Tags: time-series, estimation, maximum-likelihood, markov-process, markov-chain

since Ive received feedback that my previous question was not well-recieved Ill just have to give it another shot.

I am estimating Markov Regime Switching Models, and I am getting different results dependent on the order of my variables.

Estimation 1:

```
Y = "ln(EUR/NOK)";
X = LN_OIL, dummyoil;
R = Constant, "ln(EUR/NOK)_1", R1_SPR;
```

Estimation 2:

```
Y = "ln(EUR/NOK)";
X = LN_OIL, dummyoil;
R = "ln(EUR/NOK)_1", R1_SPR, Constant;
```

As you can see I have altered the order of the regime switching variables. This yield a better estimation of the models significance. The result for the variables of interest follows:

Estimation 1:

```
                    Coefficient    Std.Error    t-value  t-prob

  LN_OIL             -0.00269873    0.007599   -0.355   0.723
  dummyoil            0.00247058    0.008581    0.288   0.774
```

Estimation 2:

```
                    Coefficient    Std.Error    t-value  t-prob

   LN_OIL           -0.00119091    0.0002019    -5.90   0.000
   dummyoil          0.000324502   0.0001849     1.75   0.081
```

I know MRS models use ML estimation, but it only affects the models when I use more than one regime, thus a normal ML estimation yield no difference in output.

Why do I get different results by altering the order? It is curious that the non-switching variables gets different values by altering the order of the regime switching ones..

Does ML estimate variable 1 first, then 2.. etc?

Comment: What software are you using? What code did you run? I doubt this question can be answered w/o that information.

Comment: Estimation 1 and 2 is the actual code, I have removed dataset and the time period code as I thought it was irrelevant. I use OxMetrics, and therefore the code is Ox code.

Answer (score 0):

A Markov Switching Model should be trying to estimate a parameter value for each regime your are in.  I would image you are not looking at the full set of estimated parameters.

For example, you should be seeing a LN_Oil coefficient for each regime.  The resultant sensitivity of ln(EUR/NOK) to LN_OIL is conditional on the regime you are in.  To get the current total sensitivity, you need to multiply each of the coefficients by the estimated probability that you are in a regime.

I would assume that by switching the order of the regimes, you are only looking at the coefficient according to that regime and so of course the values changed.

Please include the statistical software you are using or a code example.

Comment: As you can see from the code, the LN_OIL and dummyoil is not switching. Thus I believe this will be estimated for the whole dataset, independent of the regimes. Estimation 1 and 2 is the actual code, I have removed dataset and the time period code as I thought it was irrelevant. I use OxMetrics, and therefore the code is Ox code. Thanks for reply tho :)

Comment: I was referring to the ordering of your regime variables which have switched (and was the crux of your question).  I would confirm that you are indeed looking at the unconditional estimates rather than the conditional ones.